# TypeScript - Why to use typings?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have some interfaces written in a `typings.d.ts` file, and I am not sure if I should use it or not. Are there any advantages of using typings over using `any`, other than defining the types of fields? Are there any use cases that using typings is considerably differs from using `any`?

Answer (score 1):

You are negating the type safety benefits of using typescript by just using any everywhere. Yes, you can do it (*obviously*) but why would you? If that is what you want just go back to using JavaScript (*and maybe [babel](https://babeljs.io/) for browser compatibility*). Personally, I would recommend you always use defined and appropriate types where possible.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript brings a great level of type safety and auto-completion to your development experience. If a typing is available for external code, it is well worth using.

If you are faced with creating a typing for "other code", you need to make an economic decision. In this case, `any` would represent the same risk as just using JavaScript for that area of code. If it is a small portion of your code, this may well be enough.

If you want to reduce the risk further, you could look at the most common calls into that code, or the most complex calls into that code, and [extend the definition gradually](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/01/complex-typescript-definitions-made-easy/).

So take a balanced economic view of the risk of having no type information (`any`) vs the cost of producing and maintaining the type information... and if it is your code, consider dropping it into a TypeScript file instead as an experiment - it may be quicker to fix any compiler warnings and get free type inference than it is to produce a definition.